# Displaying image using ColdFusion from BLOB

Tags: coldfusion

I want to display an image from a database. I'm using data type BLOB for that image.

I've already tried `#CharsetEncode(viewPoint.ppp_icons, "ASCII")#`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

```
<cfimage action="writeToBrowser" source="#imageBlob#">
```

http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/Tags_i_02.html

OR... Use [Data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) (w/ limited browser support).

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,#toBase64(imageBlob)#" />
```

Comment: when I use <cfimage action="writeToBrowser" source="#imageBlob#">
i got this error 'ColdFusion was unable to create an image from the specified source file'.

Comment: hmm, you sure your BLOB was persisted correctly?  Maybe specifying format = "png|jpg|jpeg" might help.

Comment: How to resize image when to insert into database.Size of the image is to big.I want to resize the image.

Comment: @yuki You want `cfimage` tag with `action = "resize"
`, see CF8/CF9 manual for details.

Comment: @yuki when resizing images you may want to consider using some third party image manipulation.  I have run into coldfusion balking on many images that it doesn't understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
<cfcontent reset="Yes" type="image/gif" variable="#QueryName.BlobColumn#" />
```

EDIT: To clarify, you would place this code in a separate template.  Which you would place the call for in the src attribute of your img tag.  You would pass the primary key of the database table and the new template would lookup and grab the blob column to be outputted.

I believe it would be better to keep all blob data in separate requests, because if you were trying to display many files on a page it would be best to let the page load up first rather than have the page load time wait until all blob data could be downloaded from the sql server to the coldfusion server.  Reducing initial page load times is of crucial importance to usability.

As an addendum, if these files are going to be accessed frequently, then it will also be best to have the file be cache on the web server and have the separate template redirect to the cached file.